# Android: Difficulty starting a fragment inside of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So, I previously asked a question, and got a bit of help, but ultimately, I decided that I needed to be more clear.

Basically, I have an app. The Main activity is a tabbed activity/swipe view. The first page consists of Main_Fragment, which consists of two other fragments (A and B) within them. Fragment A contains a button, that I am trying to have when pressed, will launch a different fragment to either go ontop of fragment A and B, replace them or Main_fragment.

Where I am getting stuck is what code I would need to use for the Fragment Transaction. Previously I used this code, when Main_Fragment, was just an activity, and it worked out well, but now I am unsure on what I would need to do.

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fragment = new DayViewFragment();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Firstly I think I would need to use getParentFragment() somehow, and I am unsure on how, and secondly I am unsure what do replace for android.R.id.content, especially, when the code is inside a fragment inside of a fragment.

If any clarification is needed, please ask. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to implement this type of functionality is to use an interface callback from the Fragment to the Activity.

Android Studio 1.2.2 will even automatically create interface callback code if you check the "Include interface callbacks?" checkbox when creating a new Fragment.

Here is the general code structure for the Fragment:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnMainFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private Button exampleButton;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    public static MainActivityFragment newInstance() {
        MainActivityFragment fragment = new MainActivityFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        exampleButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        exampleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.buttonClicked("test value");
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnMainFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnMainFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    public interface OnMainFragmentInteractionListener {
        void buttonClicked(String val);
    }
}
```

Then the Activity will implement the interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements MainActivityFragment.OnMainFragmentInteractionListener {
```

And implement the interface method:

```
@Override
public void buttonClicked(String val) {

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fragment = new DayViewFragment();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
    ft.commit();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, looking through this now, just to make sure, this should work on a swipe view/tabbed activity?

Comment: @HaHaHaHAHungry That might complicate it a bit, but you should be able to make the code work.  I'll do some tests later to try to re-create the architecture of your code and see what challenges arise.  One question, is DayViewFragment a different tab, or should it replace the current tab?

Comment: Just got it working with my code, and there seem to be no errors. Thank you so much man, you do not know how long I have been struggling on this. But I was trying to have it just replace the tab. However, right now it seems to be overriding the swipe view, so you cannot access it until you remove the fragment, which is fine for what I am doing. Again though ,thanks so much

Comment: How would I pass variables to the function buttonClicked?

Comment: @ha just define the callback method with whatever parameters you need, and then pass the variables you need in the parameters.  You can also define multiple methods in the interface if you need to, just be sure to implement all methods in the Activity!

Comment: it's giving me an error that "I am not overriding from it's superclass". So i believe i would need to use super, but I am not sure how

Comment: @ha I just updated the answer to show how to add one String parameter to the example interface callback.  The method definition in the Activity and the Fragment need to match exactly.