# How to Perform an Action Based on User's Selection on Dialog Fragment List

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to perform an action (in this case display a smiley in `ImageView` for each mood selected) based on user's selection from a `Dialogfragment list`.
My code builds and runs successfully, but when I `click` Ok `button`, my app crashes: "Unfortunately, Dialog List has stopped."

Here's my `DialogFragment class`

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SingleChoiceClass extends DialogFragment {

final CharSequence[] items = {"Ecstatic", "Happy", "Indifferent", "Upset"};
String selection;
private int item;
public ImageView imageView;


@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Select Your Mood");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            switch (arg1) {
                case 0:
                    selection = (String) items[arg1];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selection = (String) items[arg1];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    selection = (String) items[arg1];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    selection = (String) items[arg1];
                    break;

            }

        }   // TODO: 11/4/15 WHY IS APP CRASHING WHEN I setImageResource
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            if (items[item].equals("Ecstatic")) {
                // Do stuff
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_smiley);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Happy")) {
                // Do stuff
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_smiley);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Indifferent")) {
                // Do stuff
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange_smiley);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Upset")) {
                // Do stuff
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_smiley);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And here's my `MainActivity class`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    SingleChoiceClass my_dialog = new SingleChoiceClass();
    my_dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "my_dialog");
    my_dialog.setCancelable(false);


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    }

}
```

Finally, how can I get user's selection without using the OK button as is the default practice in most android inbuilt apps? See image below:

[image]

Comment: What's the point on nesting methods inside of methods instead of declare that methods normally so the code gains in readability and allows to use the methods in another points of the solution? Sorry but when I start to read a nested method declaration I usually stop reading and go to wash my eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my challenge like this:

I retained Daniel Nugent's suggestion for `MainActivity`. But I changed my `DialogFragment class` like this:

```
public class SingleChoiceClass extends DialogFragment {

final CharSequence[] items = {"Ecstatic", "Happy", "Indifferent", "Upset"};
String selection;
private int item;


@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Select Your Mood");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            switch (arg1) {
                case 0:
                    selection = (String) items[arg1];
                    // Do your magic
                    activity.setImage(R.drawable.green_smiley);
                    dismiss();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    selection = (String) items[arg1];
                    // Do your magic
                    activity.setImage(R.drawable.yellow_smiley);
                    dismiss();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    selection = (String) items[arg1];
                    // Do your magic
                    activity.setImage(R.drawable.orange_smiley);
                    dismiss();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    selection = (String) items[arg1];
                    // Do your magic
                    activity.setImage(R.drawable.red_smiley);
                    dismiss();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {      
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Exit app
            activity.finish(); 
            // Or try to relaunch dialog
       }
    });
    return builder.create();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an orphaned `imageView` in your DialogFragment, that is probably causing a NullPointerException.  First and foremost, remove all `imageView` references in the DialogFragment.

In order to fix your main issue, first create a method in MainActivity that is called by the DialogFragment when OK is clicked:

```
public void setImage(int imageID) {
    imageView.setImageResource(imageID);
}
```

Then, add the code to call that method from the DialogFragment:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Added:
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        if (items[item].equals("Ecstatic")) {
            // Do stuff
            //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_smiley); //removed
            //Added:
            if (activity != null) {
                  activity.setImage(R.drawable.green_smiley);
            }

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (items[item].equals("Happy")) {
            // Do stuff
            //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_smiley);
            //Added:
            if (activity != null) {
                  activity.setImage(R.drawable.R.drawable.yellow_smiley);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (items[item].equals("Indifferent")) {
            // Do stuff
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange_smiley);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (items[item].equals("Upset")) {
            // Do stuff
            //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_smiley);
            //Added:
            if (activity != null) {
                  activity.setImage(R.drawable.red_smiley);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
return builder.create();
}
```

You will also need to make `imageView` a member variable of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

//Added:
ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    SingleChoiceClass my_dialog = new SingleChoiceClass();
    my_dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "my_dialog");
    my_dialog.setCancelable(false);

    //modified:
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    }

    public void setImage(int imageID) {
        imageView.setImageResource(imageID);
    }

}
```

Note that you might want to use interface callbacks instead of calling the method directly on the Activity, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31798511/4409409) for details.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and code. I tried it just as you suggested but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Mandroid I just updated the answer, you just need to make `imageView` a member variable of MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works runs without errors but the green_smiley gets displayed for all cases irrespective of my selected option. I don't know why its not displaying the selected one as displayed by the toast.  Any suggestions?  It appears to be displaying only the first drawable image for all the conditions.

Comment: Though your answer didn't exactly work as I wanted, it pointed me in the right direction. I decided to take off the `if` statements completely and just set the image directly in the `switch` statement.

Comment: I understand the code, buy I really hate that weird sintax with nested methods, why don't use delegates so declared methods can be used in more than a point of the solution?

Comment: @Windgate The code in this answer was a direct copy of the code in the question, with the minimum amount of changes to get it to work!  Of course production code would look much different.