# Passing data from Fragment to it's Container Activity is not working. Any ideas?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, listener

I'm trying to pass variable data back to a Fragment's Containing Activity but it just doesn't seem to be working.

**In the fragment I have:**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

   public String profile_id;
   OnPassIdListener onPassIdListener;

   private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
       @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            ...

        }

            onPassIdListener.passId(profile_id);

        }

   public void onAttach(Context context) {
       super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            onPassIdListener = (OnPassIdListener) context;
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    public interface OnPassIdListener {
        void passId(String id);
    }
```

**In the container activity I have:**

```
@Override
public void passId(String id) {

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prof_id_test);
    textview.setText(id);

}
```

However when the textview.setText is called, it is set to null... meaning that the variable is empty.

Additionally, I have checked that the variable actually contains data BEFORE it is passed to the activity and it does so it must be something to do with the way I am passing it over.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: please post the code where you actually call onPassIdListener.passId(profile_id) in your fragment.

Comment: you need to create the view inside the onCreateView...

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla how do you mean?

Comment: @Charlieabee more than sure that textview will get null value... the view needs to be create as soon as the fragment is visible (over the onCreateView class from the Fragment)

Comment: @Charlieabee try to log a message in the catch block (inside onAttach) to check that you are implementing the interface.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla why would that be?

Comment: @JDev what should the log message be? sorry im very very new to all of this

Comment: Log.e("InterfaceCheck", "You must implement the interface."); // Put this line inside the catch block

Comment: @JDev Tried that, the log message didn't appear so I assume that I am implementing the interface properly?

Comment: hmm, weird. We need to continue this conversation in chat. This is taking too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95153/discussion-between-charlieabee-and-jdev).

Comment: If the interface implementation is the problem, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31798511

Comment: still not working! no luck @DanielNugent

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attached activity calling it like

```
ContainerActivity activity = (ContainerActivity) getActivity();
```

Then just use their methods

```
activity.passId("");
```

Comment: This would work, but @charlie is close to having it working with an interface, which is the preferred and recommended implementation.