# Call a function of Activity from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to call the function Ask() of MainActivity from fragment2.
How can I call a function of MainActivity from fragment2?
I want to import results into a page called from fragment2.

Edit:
I already see that discussion, but don't have the solution of my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call an activity method from a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment)

Comment: You can call it directly using `getActivity()` and casting it to MainActivity, but using an interface is better as it decouples the Fragment and the Activity, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31798511/4409409

Comment: Use interface to call the method in the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that function static, after that you can access that function in Fragment e.g. MainActivity.Ask();

Answer (score 0):

From fragment to activty:

```
((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();
```

From activity to fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

//if you added fragment via layout xml
YourFragmentClass fragment =    (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
fragment.yourPublicMethod();
```

If you added fragment via code and used a tag string when you added your fragment, use findFragmentByTag instead:

```
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentByTag("yourTag");
```

Cheers!

Comment: I had already tried this method before, but don't work with my code.

Comment: @Question, write your codes down here and then we(StackOverFlow) can see/understand what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

> call to function Ask() of MainActivity from fragment2.

For this you need a create a `interface` in your `fragment2`. The below code is an example from the document. You shouldn't ignore the `onAttach` method in your fragment as well.

```
public class Fragment2 extends ListFragment {
    OnCallActivityListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnCallActivityListener {
        public void callAskMethod();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnCallActivityListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Now the fragment can deliver messages to the activity by calling the `callAskMethod()` method (or other methods in the interface) using the mCallback instance of the `OnCallActivityListener` interface.

For example, the following method in the fragment is called when the user clicks on a list item. The fragment uses the callback interface to deliver the event to the parent activity.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Send the event to the host activity
    mCallback.callAskMethod();
}
```

After that you should implement the interface in your host activity.

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements Fragment2.OnCallActivityListener{
    ...

    public void callAskMethod() {
        // Do something here 
        ask();
    }
}
```

So that is it. You have called `ask()` method from `fragment2` fragment.

> I want to import results into a page called from fragment2.

The host activity can deliver messages to a fragment by capturing the `Fragment` instance with `findFragmentById()`, then directly call the fragment's public methods.

In your `MainActivity you can call send the result to the fragment.

```
Fragment2 fragment2 = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);
```

So you have a instance value of the `Fragment2` in `MainActivity`. So you can any public method of the `fragment2` from there.

for example

```
fragment2.doSomething();
```

That's it.